# PHP (on Vagrant) Connect to Microsoft SQL server 2014

Tags: php, sql-server, centos, vagrant

I am working Locally on Windows 10. And I have a vagrant [*Virtualbox Version 5.0.24 r108355*] setup with the following Configurations:

1. CentOS release 6.8 (Final)
2. PHP 5.6.25
3. [mssql](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) Library version FreeTDS
4. Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)

Also, I have installed Microsoft SQL Server 2014 on it.

## [Queries]

- Is this possible to Connect to MS-SQL from a Vagrant Machine.
- If NO, then Why ?
- if YES, then what are the different ways ?

### Further Notes:

I have installed wamp server 64 [PHP 5.6.16] locally and installed the [sqlsvr](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php)  extension. I am able to connect and access the Same SQL server DB in it.

But when try on Vagrant box with [mssql](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php), it throws an error message

```
Unable to connect to server: xxx.xxx.x.x
```